# Get Correlation coefficient from Two Dataframes Using R

Tags: r, dataframe, dplyr, plyr

I need to get correlation coefficient using two dataframes.

- First Data Frame

```
## ML
generate1 <- seq(ymd_h("2021-11-01-00"), ymd_h("2021-11-01-03"), by = "hours")
datex1 <- date(generate1)
generate2 <- seq(ymd_h("2021-11-02-00"), ymd_h("2021-11-02-03"), by = "hours")
datex2 <- date(generate2)
hourx <- hour(generate1)
method <- c(rep("ARIMA",8),rep("LSTM",8))
books <- c(390,154,154,153,352,170,229,124,458,224,196,485,492,235,139,116)
shirts <- c(312,397,119,357,464,444,453,155,484,454,282,288,141,262,148,258)
shoes <- c(306,274,480,330,143,190,213,477,141,323,316,473,269,149,333,145)
hats <- c(107,101,363,436,282,377,435,381,427,102,100,471,475,134,479,250)

data.predicted <- data.frame(datex = c(datex1,datex2,datex1,datex2),
                             hour = rep(hourx,4), method = method, 
                             books, shirts, shoes, hats)

#data.predicted
#        datex hour method books shirts shoes hats
#1  2021-11-01    0  ARIMA   390    312   306  107
#2  2021-11-01    1  ARIMA   154    397   274  101
#3  2021-11-01    2  ARIMA   154    119   480  363
#4  2021-11-01    3  ARIMA   153    357   330  436
#5  2021-11-02    0  ARIMA   352    464   143  282
#6  2021-11-02    1  ARIMA   170    444   190  377
#7  2021-11-02    2  ARIMA   229    453   213  435
#8  2021-11-02    3  ARIMA   124    155   477  381
#9  2021-11-01    0   LSTM   458    484   141  427
#10 2021-11-01    1   LSTM   224    454   323  102
#11 2021-11-01    2   LSTM   196    282   316  100
#12 2021-11-01    3   LSTM   485    288   473  471
#13 2021-11-02    0   LSTM   492    141   269  475
#14 2021-11-02    1   LSTM   235    262   149  134
#15 2021-11-02    2   LSTM   139    148   333  479
#16 2021-11-02    3   LSTM   116    258   145  250
```

- Second Data Frame

```
## real
generate <- seq(ymd_h("2021-11-01-00"), ymd_h("2021-11-01-03"), by = "hours")
datex <- date(generate)
hourx <- hour(generate)
books <- c(220,120,150,114)
shirts <- c(319,400,130,360)
shoes <- c(300,280,300,330)
hats <- c(120,140,370,400)
data.real <- data.frame(datex, hourx, books, shirts, shoes, hats)

#data.real
#       datex hourx books shirts shoes hats
#1 2021-11-01     0   220    319   300  120
#2 2021-11-01     1   120    400   280  140
#3 2021-11-01     2   150    130   300  370
#4 2021-11-01     3   114    360   330  400
```

I want to have the result like this data frame. The correlation is based on real data, if the real data only has 1 day data, so predicted data is adjusted.

```
## Result
metrics <-c("books","books","shirts","shirts","shoes","shoes","hats","hats")
method  <-c("ARIMA","LSTM","ARIMA","LSTM","ARIMA","LSTM","ARIMA","LSTM")
correlation <- c(0.946898292,0.294308358,0.999957355,0.535718183,
                 0.167424749,0.547561054,0.993560612,0.085661117)
result.cor <- data.frame(metrics, method, correlation)

#result.cor
#  metrics method correlation
#1   books  ARIMA  0.94689829
#2   books   LSTM  0.29430836
#3  shirts  ARIMA  0.99995736
#4  shirts   LSTM  0.53571818
#5   shoes  ARIMA  0.16742475
#6   shoes   LSTM  0.54756105
#7    hats  ARIMA  0.99356061
#8    hats   LSTM  0.08566112
```

We can see value of ARIMA is 0.94689829, it is from

```
ARIMA.pred <- subset(data.predicted, method == "ARIMA" & datex == "2021-11-01")

#ARIMA.pred
#       datex hour method books shirts shoes hats
#1 2021-11-01    0  ARIMA   390    312   306  107
#2 2021-11-01    1  ARIMA   154    397   274  101
#3 2021-11-01    2  ARIMA   154    119   480  363
#4 2021-11-01    3  ARIMA   153    357   330  436

data.real$books
#220 120 150 114

cor(ARIMA.pred$books, data.real$books)
#0.9468983
```

How do i create funtion to simplify and get the result?.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A data.table approach

Convert it to data.table object using **setDT()**

```
library(data.table)

setDT(data.predicted)
setDT(data.real)
```

First step is to melt data.predicted and data.real.

```
data.predicted <- melt(data.predicted, id.vars = c('datex', 'hourx', 'method'), measure.vars = c('books', 'shirts', 'shoes', 'hats'), variable.name = 'metrics', value.name = 'Value_Pred')

data.real <- melt(data.real, id.vars = c('datex', 'hourx'), measure.vars = c('books', 'shirts', 'shoes', 'hats'), variable.name = 'metrics', value.name = 'Value_Real')
```

Next step is to join both the dataset on ***datex, hourx and metrics***. Applying left join with an assumption data.predicted contains all the data points with respect to date and hour present in data.real.

```
data.predicted <- merge(data.predicted, data.real, by = c('datex', 'hourx', 'metrics'), all.x = TRUE)
```

Last step is to take correlation for each ***datex, metrics and method*** values.

```
data.predicted <- data.predicted[,.(Cor_Col = cor(Value_Pred, Value_Real)), by = .(datex,  metrics, method)]

data.predicted

         datex metrics method    Cor_Col
 1: 2021-11-01   books  ARIMA 0.94689829
 2: 2021-11-01   books   LSTM 0.29430836
 3: 2021-11-01  shirts  ARIMA 0.99995736
 4: 2021-11-01  shirts   LSTM 0.53571818
 5: 2021-11-01   shoes  ARIMA 0.16742475
 6: 2021-11-01   shoes   LSTM 0.54756105
 7: 2021-11-01    hats  ARIMA 0.99356061
 8: 2021-11-01    hats   LSTM 0.08566112
 9: 2021-11-02   books  ARIMA         NA
10: 2021-11-02   books   LSTM         NA
11: 2021-11-02  shirts  ARIMA         NA
12: 2021-11-02  shirts   LSTM         NA
13: 2021-11-02   shoes  ARIMA         NA
14: 2021-11-02   shoes   LSTM         NA
15: 2021-11-02    hats  ARIMA         NA
16: 2021-11-02    hats   LSTM         NA
```

Answer (score 1):

```r
library(lubridate)
#> 
#> Attaching package: 'lubridate'
#> The following objects are masked from 'package:base':
#> 
#>     date, intersect, setdiff, union
library(tidyverse)

generate1 <- seq(ymd_h("2021-11-01-00"), ymd_h("2021-11-01-03"), by = "hours")
datex1 <- date(generate1)
generate2 <- seq(ymd_h("2021-11-02-00"), ymd_h("2021-11-02-03"), by = "hours")
datex2 <- date(generate2)
hourx <- hour(generate1)
method <- c(rep("ARIMA", 8), rep("LSTM", 8))
books <- c(390, 154, 154, 153, 352, 170, 229, 124, 458, 224, 196, 485, 492, 235, 139, 116)
shirts <- c(312, 397, 119, 357, 464, 444, 453, 155, 484, 454, 282, 288, 141, 262, 148, 258)
shoes <- c(306, 274, 480, 330, 143, 190, 213, 477, 141, 323, 316, 473, 269, 149, 333, 145)
hats <- c(107, 101, 363, 436, 282, 377, 435, 381, 427, 102, 100, 471, 475, 134, 479, 250)

data.predicted <- data.frame(
  datex = c(datex1, datex2, datex1, datex2),
  hour = rep(hourx, 4), method = method,
  books, shirts, shoes, hats
)
generate <- seq(ymd_h("2021-11-01-00"), ymd_h("2021-11-01-03"), by = "hours")
datex <- date(generate)
hourx <- hour(generate)
books <- c(220, 120, 150, 114)
shirts <- c(319, 400, 130, 360)
shoes <- c(300, 280, 300, 330)
hats <- c(120, 140, 370, 400)
data.real <- data.frame(datex, hour = hourx, books, shirts, shoes, hats)

data.real
#>        datex hour books shirts shoes hats
#> 1 2021-11-01    0   220    319   300  120
#> 2 2021-11-01    1   120    400   280  140
#> 3 2021-11-01    2   150    130   300  370
#> 4 2021-11-01    3   114    360   330  400

data.predicted
#>         datex hour method books shirts shoes hats
#> 1  2021-11-01    0  ARIMA   390    312   306  107
#> 2  2021-11-01    1  ARIMA   154    397   274  101
#> 3  2021-11-01    2  ARIMA   154    119   480  363
#> 4  2021-11-01    3  ARIMA   153    357   330  436
#> 5  2021-11-02    0  ARIMA   352    464   143  282
#> 6  2021-11-02    1  ARIMA   170    444   190  377
#> 7  2021-11-02    2  ARIMA   229    453   213  435
#> 8  2021-11-02    3  ARIMA   124    155   477  381
#> 9  2021-11-01    0   LSTM   458    484   141  427
#> 10 2021-11-01    1   LSTM   224    454   323  102
#> 11 2021-11-01    2   LSTM   196    282   316  100
#> 12 2021-11-01    3   LSTM   485    288   473  471
#> 13 2021-11-02    0   LSTM   492    141   269  475
#> 14 2021-11-02    1   LSTM   235    262   149  134
#> 15 2021-11-02    2   LSTM   139    148   333  479
#> 16 2021-11-02    3   LSTM   116    258   145  250


covariates <- c("books", "shirts", "shoes", "hats")
methods <- c("ARIMA", "LSTM")

list(
  data.real %>% mutate(type = "real"),
  data.predicted %>% mutate(type = "predicted")
) %>%
  bind_rows() %>%
  nest(-datex) %>%
  expand_grid(
    covariate = covariates,
    method = methods
  ) %>%
  mutate(cor = list(data, covariate, method) %>% pmap_dbl(possibly(~ {
    real <- .x %>%
      filter(type == "real") %>%
      pluck(.y)
    predicted <- .x %>%
      filter(method == ..3) %>%
      pluck(.y)
    cor(real, predicted)
  }, NA))) %>%
  select(-data)
#> Warning: All elements of `...` must be named.
#> Did you want `data = c(hour, books, shirts, shoes, hats, type, method)`?
#> # A tibble: 16 x 4
#>    datex      covariate method     cor
#>    <date>     <chr>     <chr>    <dbl>
#>  1 2021-11-01 books     ARIMA   0.947 
#>  2 2021-11-01 books     LSTM    0.294 
#>  3 2021-11-01 shirts    ARIMA   1.00  
#>  4 2021-11-01 shirts    LSTM    0.536 
#>  5 2021-11-01 shoes     ARIMA   0.167 
#>  6 2021-11-01 shoes     LSTM    0.548 
#>  7 2021-11-01 hats      ARIMA   0.994 
#>  8 2021-11-01 hats      LSTM    0.0857
#>  9 2021-11-02 books     ARIMA  NA     
#> 10 2021-11-02 books     LSTM   NA     
#> 11 2021-11-02 shirts    ARIMA  NA     
#> 12 2021-11-02 shirts    LSTM   NA     
#> 13 2021-11-02 shoes     ARIMA  NA     
#> 14 2021-11-02 shoes     LSTM   NA     
#> 15 2021-11-02 hats      ARIMA  NA     
#> 16 2021-11-02 hats      LSTM   NA
```

<sup>Created on 2021-11-25 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>